# RVM permission denied error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have done a multi user installation of RVM on a machine running Debian 7. My project on the machine uses ruby v2.2.2 and a gemset. I have a .ruby-version file located in my project root with the contents `2.2.2@my-project-name`
Now, when i cd into my project dir i get the following errors:

```
Regenerating ruby-2.2.2 wrappers........
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment': Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 93: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 99: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 99: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 99: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 99: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 100: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 100: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment: line 99: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/environment: Permission denied
```

Any way to fix this?

Please Help
Thank You.

Comment: Would you mind to share `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/environment` around 90:100 lines?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally installed a new version of Ruby with root instead with restricted user.

You can solve this in that way:

Login to your server via SSH and go to directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/` and look whats the user of former versions:

```
sreuter@localhost:/usr/local/rvm/gems$ ls -lah
total 28K
drwxrwsrwx  7 root    rvm 4.0K Mar 29 14:32 .
drwxrwsrwx 26 root    rvm 4.0K Feb 21 14:10 ..
...
drwxrwsr-x 10 sreuter rvm 4.0K Mar 29 13:36 ruby-2.4.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 sreuter rvm   52 Feb 24 07:05 ruby-2.4.0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
drwxrwsr-x 10 root    rvm 4.0K Mar 29 14:45 ruby-2.4.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    rvm   52 Mar 29 14:32 ruby-2.4.1@global -> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
```

You'll see that the latest directory `ruby-2.4.1` and it's symbolic link belongs to root instead of restricted user as the other directories.

Change the user as follows:

```
sudo chown -R sreuter:rvm ruby-2.4.1*
```

(Change the user and group name to your needs)